# Are there any factors that change the spawning of mobs?

Tags: dont-starve

What I mean by the title is if you take pig's home while they're dead, does that stop them from spawning? Or does having them die from a mob or you killing them change their spawn time? If you could also post the normal respawn time that would be nice too.

Comment: I am sorry for the butcherd grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the wiki, when a pig is killed they will always respawn in their house. They respawn the morning immediately after their death.
As far as I can tell, this is regardless of what killed them or whether you occupy their house.

Additional information can be found at [the wiki page](http://dontstarvewiki.net/index.php/Pig).

Comment: Do you know if destroying their house stops them from spawning?

Comment: Given that's their respawn point then yes, they wont respawn any more. You can of course build a pig house to get a new pig.

Comment: No trouble at all c:

Comment: From the video's I watched on youtube, I was told you can kill a pigman, then attack its house and it (or on of its compatriots) will immediately spawn again to protect its home.